# package had UID -1

Tags: android

I just saw a weired error in Android Studio Logcat, this is first time I have seen this type of error, I googled but found nothing. Please suggest the fix if anyone has faced the same problem.

```
    2018-12-07 16:10:13.377 1295-1409/? E/PackageManager.DexOptimizer: Well this is awkward; package com.itsmysun.sitesurvey.application.MyApplication had UID -1
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageDexOptimizer.performDexOptLI(PackageDexOptimizer.java:150)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageDexOptimizer.performDexOpt(PackageDexOptimizer.java:126)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:19987)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageTracedLI(PackageManagerService.java:19547)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-wrap35(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$9.run(PackageManagerService.java:16810)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
2018-12-07 16:10:15.802 945-1617/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1027068705.tmp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456992/android-permisson-bind-notification-listener-service-is-not-working) link out. It seems like the person who asked the question had a similar issue.

Comment: @tomerpacific Sure, Let me check once.

Comment: Checked the mentioned link, hope I will be able to solve the problem, Will update you after that.

Comment: How was it going, man? Did you find a way to solve this problem?